# Is it ok to say that "I am happy for a volunteer position as well"

Tags: grammar

Is it ok to say that  "I am happy for a volunteer position as well".

Comment: You would be happy "to accept" or "to take" a volunteer position.

Answer (score 2):

"I'm happy to take/take up/have/hold a volunteer position" would be fine. If you have already gained the position, then you may be happy **to have gotten it**. Other examples of using "happy" with prepositions, which I can think of right now, are: 
I'm not too happy **about** your attitude.
So you're getting married! I'm really happy **for** you.
I'm quite happy **with** the way things are going.